# making an image button shape the same as the image

Tags: android, image, button, shapes

I am using android API 1.5, and trying to make some images for the user to click on. The images have very random shapes. When i put the images on an image button, the button itself is always rectangle. so you can click the button without pressing the actual image. I want the user to press the image to click the button instead of them pressing a blank spot on the button and still clicking the button.

Is there a way to make the clickable area of am image button match a random shaped image?

Comment: show what you have done. and then ask for the problem.

Comment: Have fun: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/